# Pyglet copy and paste a text in an IncrementalTextLayout() object

Tags: python, windows, pyglet

Is there a way to make a simple "copy and paste" in Pyglet?

I need to copy a text (<kbd>ctrl + c</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>ctrl + v</kbd>) it into a `IncrementalTextLayout()` object in Pyglet, is this possible?

I'm using Python 3.4, Pyglet 1.2.4 and I run on Windows.

Code example:

```
import pyglet

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = pyglet.window.Window(617, 200)
    batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
    document = pyglet.text.document.FormattedDocument("Colar texto aqui!")
    document.set_style(0, len(document.text), dict(font_name='Arial', font_size=25, color=(255, 255, 255, 255)))
    layout = pyglet.text.layout.IncrementalTextLayout(document, 300, 50, batch=batch)
    caret = pyglet.text.caret.Caret(layout, color=(255, 255, 255))
    window.push_handlers(caret)

    @window.event
    def on_draw():
        """Desenha a tela."""
       window.clear()
       batch.draw()
       window.push_handlers(caret)

    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: You may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @boardrider question editaded.

Comment: It's unclear if you need to `cut-and-paste` text into your text editor, or if you want to create Python code that will give you the functionality of `cut-and-paste.`

Comment: @boardrider It's copy and past **into Pyglet**, seeing as OP want's to paste into `IncrementalTextLayout()` which is a part of Pyglet IIRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another developer resolved this with the Pyperclip and put your functions in the on_key_press method of the Window in Pyglet. Follow the code bellow:

```
def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
    if modifiers is 18 and pyglet.window.key.MOD_CTRL and int(symbol) is pyglet.window.key.V:
        if self.input_text:
            self.on_text(pyperclip.paste())

    elif modifiers is 18 and pyglet.window.key.MOD_CTRL and int(symbol) is pyglet.window.key.C:
            pyperclip.copy(self.input_text.document.text)
```